# Azure Media Services - The video playback was aborted due to a corruption... (0x20400003)

Tags: azure, html5-video, mp4, azure-media-services

I have uploaded my MP4 files to Azure then converted them to H264 1080p Streaming format.
When I try to play it from the player, it gives me the following error:

[image]

The same for all browsers. When I download the processed MP4 files from the underlying storage account, they play just fine.

This is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
    <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
    <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
    <link href="//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/1.8.1/skins/amp-default/azuremediaplayer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/1.8.1/azuremediaplayer.min.js"></script>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>


    <video id="vid1" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin amp-big-play-centered" autoplay controls width="640" height="400" data-setup='{"logo": { "enabled": false }, "controls": true, "autoplay": false, "nativeControlsForTouch": true}'>
    <source src="https://mediatest12.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/96fe4710-a1e2-4384-a849-93a0fceb1d40/big_buck_bunny_1280x720_30mb.ism/manifest(format=mpd-time-csf)" type="application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml" />
    <p class="amp-no-js">
        To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that supports HTML5 video
    </p>
    </video>

    <video id="vid2" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin amp-big-play-centered" autoplay controls width="640" height="400" data-setup='{"logo": { "enabled": false }, "controls": true, "autoplay": false, "nativeControlsForTouch": true}'>
    <source src="https://igmediawe.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/27472dba-a353-429e-b305-2879e32f65ea/wi005-packing_ecomm_pack_scan.ism/manifest(format=mpd-time-csf)" 
        type="application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml" />
    <p class="amp-no-js">
        To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that supports HTML5 video
    </p>
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

The first video works, the other doesn't.

Here is the page I'm trying to use it on: the exact same player settings work with another video:

https://opreports.azurewebsites.net/media.html

What am I doing wrong? I get the same error if I try to play it from within the Azure Portal as well.

The originally uploaded source video:

```
MP4
H.264/MPEG-4 AVC
1680 x 924
30fps
No audio stream
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got help from Microsoft support eventually, quoting their answer below.

---

"The issue is that the second video is video-only.  According to the bottom of http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/features.html, Azure Media Player does not support audio-only or video-only files. They must contain both audio and video. The reason for this is the support for certain features within the Media Source Extensions in most browsers and how we implement them.

Because of this we included a feature in the Azure Media Services Explorer (http://aka.ms/amse) that allows you to add a silent audio track to a video-only source file or a black screen to an audio-only file:

[image]

To get to this, right click on the video you want to encode, choose Encode → Encode asset(s) with Media Encoder Standard (MES)... → Advanced tab."